# Saving documents on mongoose on console app keep hanging the execution

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a fairly simple nodejs console app using mongoose, and I am trying to save a document and end the program execution. The problem is that it hangs in a waiting state.

I just found some other questions like this, informing things like trying to close the connection, but I had no luck with the responses. I already tried everything that I found on docs, and answers and nothing worked.

My code is pretty straightforward:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

let personSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {type: String},
    age: {type: Number}
  },
  { collection: "person" }
);

let personModel = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/People", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}).then(
    () => {
        personModel.create({
            name: "Alex",
            age: 40
        });
    },
    err => {
        console.error("Error", err);
    }
);
```

What I already tried:

- Close the connection after create. Results on the error: `Topology is closed. Please connect`.
- Setting `keepAlive` to false: no effect
- Setting `bufferCommands` to false: no effect

Is there a way to fix this behavior? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to `await` the `create`?

Comment: Not sure. I can't await the creation using this code sample, since this is the whole file, I am not using any functions, right?

Comment: `() =>` is a function header